# Is there a Linux app that will prevent a laptop from going to sleep while on battery power when a specific app is running?

Tags: 20.04, suspend, power-management, application-development, battery

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 on my laptop, I would like to know if there is an app to prevent my laptop from going to sleep while on battery power when a specific app is running.
Thanks in Advance,
Narika

Answer (score 1):

You can install the Caffeine extension.

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/517/caffeine/

After it is installed, go to the Caffeine settings (either from the Extensions app or from the Gnome Tweaks app) and add the application that will always turn caffeine "on" (i.e. prevent the computer from sleeping).

Note that Caffeine works regardless of whether the laptop is plugged in or using battery.